# DC.js: Unable to make the line plot in decreasing order

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

Intially I have the decreasing line plot but when I do cross filtering it won't be decreasing any more as the x-axis labels become fixed. I want this X-axis labels to be dynamic and to be arranged on the basis of the y-axis values. I ain't able to find the syntax or what to be used for this case.

[image]

I initialize my chart like

```
lineChart2
    .height(600)
    .width(lineChart2.width()*0.95) //give it a width
    // .margins({top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 100})//give it margin left of 100 so that the y axis ticks dont cut off
    .dimension(lineTypeDimension)
    .group(lineTypeGroup) 
    .ordering(function(kv) { 
        console.log("val:",kv.value);
        return -kv.value; })
    .x(d3.scaleOrdinal( ))
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .interpolate('linear')
    .elasticY(true)
    .renderArea(true)
     .renderlet(function(chart){chart.selectAll("circle.dot").style("fill-opacity", 1).on('mousemove', null).on('mouseout', null);})

    // .renderTitle(true)
    .renderLabel(true)
    .xAxis().ticks(3).tickFormat(function(d) {
        return d;
    });
```

Here is the working demo:
https://blockbuilder.org/ninjakx/302eaacb0a333e67c46c55dd60d27811

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the line chart to recalculate the X domain on each redraw by setting

```
lineChart2
    .elasticX(true)
```

The feature was originally intended for linear scales in order to calculate the min and max each redraw. Ordinal scales work differently, with a sequence of domain and range values, but setting elasticX will will get the chart to recalculate the scale.